# Node-Minimatch/Regex: Match subdirectories within a specified subdirectory

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, regex-negation, minimatch

I would like to match all subfolders within a given subfolder.

Let's say I have the following directories:

```
test/rock/martin
test/rock/steven
test/rock/steven/coolmusik
test/rock/steven/coolmusik/newmusic

test/pop/martin
test/pop/steven
test/pop/steven/mysubdir
test/pop/steven/anothersubdir
```

---

Now I'd like to match everything in 'rock' and 'pop', with a restriction of a given name. In this case it's 'steven'.

The following [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) glob-rule works fine so far:

```
minimatch('./test', ['!*(rock|pop|steven)'], {matchBase: true}))
```

**Translation of the rule above:**

> Hide everything that is not in rock and pop and steven.

---

But here's the problem:
As one can imagine minimatch doesn't include the subdirectories in this particular case.

I want it to be like...

```
minimatch('./test', ['!*(rock|pop|steven|PLUS_SUBDIRS_OF_STEVEN)'], {matchBase: true}))
```

...but sadly it didn't work with my rule:

```
minimatch('./test', ['!*(rock|pop|steven/**)'], {matchBase: true}))
```

**My question is:** ***How can I hide all things except for rock+pop+steven+steven's subdirectories ?***

---

A better overview of the directory-structure:

```
test
|-rock
|--martin
|--steven
|---coolmusik
|----newmusic
|-pop
|--martin
|--steven
|---mysubdir
|---anothersubdir
```

---

Also: If there's no way minimatch can handle this, how would a regular Regex for the rules above look like?

Comment: have you tried `minimatch('./test/**'` ? and it your `noglobstar` unflagged ?

Comment: Yes but it didn't work. It won't match against the path.

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot get the .gitignore-style behavior by making a list of every file and then glob-matching each one. For starters, that's ludicrously expensive (you may have a .gitignore'd folder with 100000 files in it or something), and also, you have to keep track of whether the parent was ignored. However, it gets more complicated, because a rule might cause you to have to look for specific items, if they're un-ignored with a negated rule.

**Source:** https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch/issues/8#issuecomment-5516685

The owner of 'minimatch' wrote a module called **[fstream-ignore](https://github.com/npm/fstream-ignore)** which solves this problem. 
However. That is definately out of scope and not related to my question. I end up with a regular Javascript regex, as mentioned in the original post.

---

**Regex:**

```
new RegExp(^test\/(rock|pop)(?:\/|$)(?:steven|$)(?:\/.*|$)$);
```

---

**Example:**

```js
var re = /^test\/(rock|pop)(?:\/|$)(?:steven|$)(?:\/.*|$)/mg;
var paths = 'test/rock/martin\ntest/rock/steven\ntest/rock/steven/coolmusik\ntest/rock/steven/coolmusik/newmusic\ntest/pop/martin\ntest/pop/steven\ntest/pop/steven/mysubdir\ntest/pop/steven/anothersubdir';

var match;

while ((match = re.exec(paths)) !== null) {
  if (match.index === re.lastIndex) {
    re.lastIndex++;
  }
  var old_content = document.getElementById('results').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = old_content + '<br>' + match[0];
}
```

```html
<b>Verify against:</b>
<pre>
test/rock/martin
test/rock/steven
test/rock/steven/coolmusik
test/rock/steven/coolmusik/newmusic

test/pop/martin
test/pop/steven
test/pop/steven/mysubdir
test/pop/steven/anothersubdir
</pre>

<br><hr><br>

<b>Get <u>steven</u>'s results</b>:
<div id="results"></div>
```